# Laplace's Equation - under what circumstances does it hold?

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions

I'm currently taking an EM course whereby we deal with systems that satisfy [Laplace's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$. Examples include permeable sphere in a magnetic field and metal sphere in electric field, where the problems are solved usually through boundary conditions.

But firstly, under what circumstances does Laplace's equation hold? I'm thinking there needs to be a surface of constant potential? But is that all is required?

Comment: One place to start is with [Maxwell's equations,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations) along with how they relate to the electric potential.

Comment: Since $E=-\nabla \phi$, does it mean that $\nabla \cdot E = 0$? Then by using divergence theorem, it either means that the field is zero over the surface, or the net flux into the surface is zero.

Comment: Yes, but it's simpler than that... Compare of $\nabla \cdot E$ with one of Maxwell's equations.

Comment: $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=-\nabla^2\phi=0$ doesn't necessarily follow from $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi$, as the divergence of a gradient is not necessarily zero. However, in a charge-free region ($\rho=0$), it is, and so Laplace's equation is satisfied. Note that implicit in $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi$ is the assumption of electrostatic conditions.

Comment: So basically, *if* you're looking at a domain which has zero charge inside of it, then Laplace's equation is automatically true, and thus you can use it to reconstruct the values of $\phi$ everywhere inside the domain, based on the values of $\phi$ on the boundaries.

Comment: For simple geometries and boundary conditions, you can get exact expressions for $\phi$ using pencil and paper. For more complicated geometries, this becomes difficult, and it's easier to just program a computer to numerically solve Laplace's equation to yield $\phi$, and thus $\mathbf{E}$, everywhere inside the domain. Then, from $\mathbf{E}$ you can predict, for example, how charged particles will move around inside of the domain; this is how ion-steering optics are designed.

Answer (score 2):

> Under what circumstances does Laplace's equation hold?

In the case of electrostatics in free space, Laplace's equation holds whenever the domain in question is charge-free. This follows since $$\Delta \phi=\nabla\cdot\nabla\phi=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}=0$$
whenever $\rho=0$.

> I'm thinking there needs to be a surface of constant potential?

Not necessarily, the boundary conditions can be anything, not just constant.

In fact, if the boundaries are all at the same constant potential, then it's rather boring; the solution just becomes $\phi=\phi_b$ everywhere inside the domain, where $\phi_b$ is the constant boundary potential. In that case, $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi_b=0$, which is why the inside of a hollow metal object has zero field (Faraday cage effect).

Comment: So to summarize, laplace's equation is only true for 1. Electrostatic case, 2. free space

Comment: @user44840: Yeah, just insert Maxwell's equation $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0$ into Laplace's equation; it equals zero when $\rho=0$, ie, free space.